# Makefile extract value of while

Tags: makefile, while-loop

I did a while loop into my Makefile but I don't know how I can 'extract / update' the value of conditional variable:

```
i := 0

.PHONY: syslog
syslog:
    $Q i=$(i) ; \
         while [ $${i} -le 7 ] ; do \
           if grep -q local$$i.* "$(SYSLOG)" ; then i=`expr $$i + 1` ; else printf "\n\!myapp\nlocal$$i.*\t\t\t\t\t-/var/log/myapp.log\n" >> $(SYSLOG) && i=`expr $$i` && break ; fi ; \
         done ; \
       true ; \
    $Q echo "$i"
```

I want that if the loop does the printf when i=2 for example, after echo "$i" returns 2 but it returns 0, so I don't correctly extracting the value updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking directly.   The makefile variables are expanded when the makefile is first parsed.   After that, the recipes are run, and the recipe variables are expanded at that point, so they cannot effect the (already expanded) makefile variables.

It is possible to pass the expanded `$${i}` to a sub make though (`$(MAKE) i=$${i}`), or you could try to set  `$i` through a shell command outside of a recipe ( `i:=$(shell echo 2)` )

Comment: Thank you @john Finally I'm going to do it otherwise